# Create a loading message on tkinter file that takes a while to open

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I have a Python script that uses tkinter and on open it runs a query that takes a minute or two to run. I'd like to create a message while it's loading before the full application loads so that the user knows that it's loading. My code looks like:

```
sqlStr = 'select * from exampleTable'

df = pd.read_sql(sqlStr, conn)

*Some database manipulation*

def1:
     example def 

w = tk.Tk()
w.mainloop()
```

From this code, the application doesn't open until the database manipulation is finished. Is there a way to show some loading screen while pandas is importing the data?

Comment: why not simply build the tkinter window first then update a label that says "Query in progress" and and then "Query complete" I do this all the time. My tkinter application opens and then runs a query in a separate thread and simply update a label to let the user know a query is pending.

Comment: How could you go about updating a label?

Comment: `label_name.config(text="new text here")`

Comment: @Mike-SMT Other than that, its hard to get progressbar to work realtime right?

Comment: No. Progress bar real time is not hard to do. You just need to take advantage of threading. When it comes to a query however it will be harder to predict how long the query will take so getting an accurate progress bar for something like a query is unlikely. Unless the library is reporting on progress. Maybe Pandas reports progress I dont know myself.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Yes that what, for downloading and all its fine, i believe, but in case of query and window bootup time, im not sure, unless we run this splash screen in a separate thread?

Comment: I typically just run it saying pending query results and then add a `.`, `..`, `...` at the end of the text every second to indicate the process is still running and have a min/sec clock running to show time it takes to run. Its enough to let the user know the program is not frozen and still running fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can run your db operation in separate thread:

```
import time
import threading
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar


class TkApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.progress = Progressbar()
        threading.Thread(target=self.db).start()

    def db(self):
        self.progress.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.progress.start()
        time.sleep(5)  # do something with DB
        self.progress.stop()
        self.progress.grid_forget()


app = TkApp()
app.mainloop()
```

The result would be following:

[image]